# Export of Customer to CSV Not Working

Tags: php, magento

If i try to export customer to csv file. It's giving error. how i can resolve.
Please help me.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Array::getAllOptions() in /home/prestofr/public_html/newstaging/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity/Abstract.php on line 369

Comment: Any custom modules installed?

Comment: It's caused by a "bad" attribute.  Try running `select * from eav_attribute where entity_type_id = 1 and backend_code = 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array'` to find it.